# Cannot get connection string from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm building my own API web app using ASP.NET Core 2.0. But I cannot get my connection string stored in `appsettings.json`.

Here is my code in the `Startup.cs` file, the `connection` variable holds the connection string, but somehow it is always null:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
   //Add connection to SQL Server Db in appsettings.json
   var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("CoinToolDbContext");
   services.AddDbContext<CoinToolDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
   services.AddMvc();
}
```

And here is my appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "CoinToolDbContext": "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=CoinToolDb;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my project folder and file structure:

[image: Solution structure in Visual Studio with the appsettings file at the root]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the ConnectionStrings element outside the Logging section (The closing bracket was in the wrong place)

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
       }
      },
      "Console": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Warning"
        }
      },
    },
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "CoinToolDbContext": "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=CoinToolDb;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
    }      
}
```

And setup the context this way:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{
    services.AddDbContext<CoinToolDbContext>(options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CoinToolDbContext")));
}
```

Comment: Now you also moved the `Console` section out of the `Logging` section…

Comment: Thanks. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

In your `appsettings.json`, the `ConnectionStrings` section is **within** the `Logging` section. So you cannot resolve the connection strings from the root `IConfiguration` object.

You should change your configuration so that `ConnectionStrings` is at the root:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    …
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "CoinToolDbContext": "…"
  }
}
```